# How to "render" a Box2D scene on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm currently using box2d with cocos2d on iPhone. I have quite a complex scene set up, and I want the end user to be able to record it as video as part of the app. I have implemented a recorder using the AVAssetWriter etc. and have managed to get it recording frames grabbed from OpenGL pixel data.

However, this video recording seems to a) slow down the app a bit, but more importantly b) only record a few frames per second at best.

This led me to the idea of rendering a Box2D scene, manually firing ticks and grabbing an image every tick. However, dt could be an issue here.

Just wondering if anyone has already done this, or if anyone has any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A good solution I guess would be to use a screen recorder solution like [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) or similar...

Comment: Does such an application exist for iOS?

Comment: I think so, but such video recording requires high CPU for on the flight compression, which devices are a bit weak. Do them on simulator when you can...

Comment: Thanks Vincent. The idea is to allow the end user to record whenever they like and share to their Youtube. I should have made this more clear in the initial question - I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your box2d is a good idea... however, you would want to used a fixed-time step. if you use dt the steps in the physics simulation will be to big, and box2d will be unstable and jittery.

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

The frame rate will take a hit, but you'll get every frame.  I don't think you'll be able to record every frame and still maintain a steady frame rate - that seems to be asking a lot of the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the tip mfredrickson. I have checked out the link and that's definitely going to be integral to a working solution.